# DataTables warning: table id=T_Pd - Invalid JSON response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo el Problema de respuesta invalida de JSON pero la respuesta esta correcta.

Mi problema es que quiero traer datos a una DataTable JQuery, por medio de una consulta AJAX enviando 3 parametros.
la parte que falla es cuando trae la respuesta en formato JSON, me dice que es invalida, pero esta bien formateada. 
alguien que me guie?

CONSULTA

```
        $Q= 'CALL `sel_pd_cte`('.$id.', "'.$_POST['ini'].'", "'.$_POST['fin'].'")';

        $QE=$enlace->Query($Q);

        $i=0;

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($QE)) {

            $Tpd["Data"][$i][]= array_map("utf8_encode", $row);
            $i=$i + 1;
        }

          echo json_encode($Tpd);
?>
```

RESPUESTA:

```
{"Data":[[["1","Razon 2","2017-05-10","8000.00","Aprobado","Entregado"]],[["2","Razon 2","2017-05-15","5000.00","Aprobado","Entrega Parcial"]]]}
```

Trae el resultado desde el PHP:

```js
 Pedidos(){
      $('#T_Pd').DataTable({
                   "destroy":true,
                    "ajax":{
                        "method": "POST",
                        "url": "tped.php"
                      },

                       "columns":[
                            {"Data":"0"},
                            {"Data":"1"},
                            {"Data":"2"},
                            {"Data":"3"},
                            {"Data":"4"},
                            {"Data":"5"}
                          ]
          })
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en que recibes de esta forma

```
{
  "Data": [
    [
      ["1", "Razon 2", "2017-05-10", "8000.00", "Aprobado", "Entregado"]
    ],
    [
      ["2", "Razon 2", "2017-05-15", "5000.00", "Aprobado", "Entrega Parcial"]
    ]
  ]
}
```

cuando debes recibir esto:

```
{
  "Data": [
    ["1", "Razon 2", "2017-05-10", "8000.00", "Aprobado", "Entregado"],
    ["2", "Razon 2", "2017-05-15", "5000.00", "Aprobado", "Entrega Parcial"]
  ]
}
```

el punto es que envías un arreglo de matrices

por lo que veo en tu php tienes esto:

```
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($QE)) {
   $Tpd["Data"][$i][]= array_map("utf8_encode", $row);
   $i=$i + 1;
 }
```

Déjalo de esta forma:

```
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($QE)) {
   array_push($Tpd["Data"],array_map("utf8_encode", $row));
 }
```

Comment: Hola JuankGlezz,
gracias por tu respuesta, ya probé y el error persiste.

Comment: @CirelRomeo he modificado el php, si mi lógica es correcta debería funcionar, pero algo así es la idea, por otro lado la prueba que hiciste como fue el resultado que te arrojo?

Comment: Glezz el resultado fue igual a tu corrección, pero sigue con el error de  **Invalid JSON response** .
Pruebo tu nueva modificación y te comento...gracias

Comment: @CirelRomeo como te devuelve el json?

Comment: `{
  "Data": [
    ["1", "Razon 2", "2017-05-10", "8000.00", "Aprobado", "Entregado"],
    ["2", "Razon 2", "2017-05-15", "5000.00", "Aprobado", "Entrega Parcial"]
  ]
}`

Comment: @CirelRomeo como tienes el javascript que llama al ajax, puedes agregarlo a tu pregunta